auto rotate settings only works in tablet mode
I have recently started using a lenovo ideapad flex which is a 2 in 1 laptop with ubuntu 24.04.01, and i observed this weird behavior that the auto-rotation feature only works when the device is fully open and set to tablet mode, which actually is the design idea behind it. The problems arise when coming back to computer mode, when this happens the last orientation gets fix and the computer stays like it until i managed to set it correctly. when using monitor system it detects the rotation sensor but it only gets modified in the 4 directional modes and not when the computer gets back to "normal" mode which is the fifth state of the sensor linked to computer mode
monitor-sensor 
   Waiting for iio-sensor-proxy to appear
+++ iio-sensor-proxy appeared
=== Has accelerometer (orientation: normal)
=== No ambient light sensor
=== No proximity sensor
   Accelerometer orientation changed: bottom-up
   Accelerometer orientation changed: normal
   Accelerometer orientation changed: left-up
   Accelerometer orientation changed: normal
   Accelerometer orientation changed: right-up
   Accelerometer orientation changed: normal


is there a GNOME setting i am missing to fix these behavior?

Please check your details; there was no release of Ubuntu in 2024-January (24.01) so are you using the April LTS or October release?
